# Is there a better way to access nested children using ref in Vue? (Grandfather - Father - Son)

Tags: vue.js, nested, vue-component, ref

For how it is structured the project, and I cannot change, I need to get a value from a Father all the way down to the Son's son (Grandfather to Son relationship). This is a code example of what I am saying.

**ComponentGrandfather.vue**

```
<component-father
  ref="refGF"
  (...)
  ><component-father>
```

**ComponentFather.vue**

```
<component-son
  ref="refF"
  (...)
  ><component-son>
```

**ComponentSon.vue**

```
<input type=text ref="valueSon"></input>
```

I know that you can access to the Son using `this.$ref.refGF.$ref.refF.$ref.valueSon.value`, but I want to know if there is a less verbose way to this, or if this is the only way to do it.

Comment: The wording is unclear if you want to get father's value in a grandchild or vice versa. The code confirms it's the latter. This is a verbose and discouraged way to do this. A value should bubble up with events instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have props for that. You can drill the prop from the GF to the Father and then to the Son.